# Wrapping labels around input controls in twitter bootstrap

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, label

I want to use html input elements in twitter bootstrap. I have a label on the left and an input element on the right. I pretty much used the example given in the bootstrap documentation. But my problem is that I don't have IDs for every input element and so I can't specify the "for"-value of the labels.

My solution in previous projects was wrapping the input element with a label, but this results in a wrong styling when I use bootstrap.

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">MyTitle: 
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" value="..." />
        </div>
    </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will this work for you?

```
<div class="control-group">
  <div class="controls">
    <label class="control-label">MyTitle:     
      <input type="text" value="..." />
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The label is above my input element now but it should be on the left.

Comment: It does appear to the left of the input. See 2nd `control-group` markup here: http://www.bootply.com/63281

Comment: Hmm, it looks like my problem is the form which is surrounding my controls: http://www.bootply.com/63287
I use form-horizontal to wrap my whole form, with my form-horizontal it looks like I described.